# Are there any wireless keyboard or mice that can be plugged in via usb when gaming?

Tags: keyboard, wireless-networking, mouse, input-device

Are there any wireless keyboard or mice that can be plugged in via usb when gaming?

Comment: just to clarify, you're looking for a keyboard and/or mouse that can be used both as wired and wireless?  (most wireless keyboards/mice plug their wireless receivers into USB, so technically any will do.  but i suspect that's not what you're asking.)

Comment: sounds like that's what he's looking for, perhaps wireless interference is a problem for his setup and when gaming it is really detrimental?

Comment: So far (I'll have better info when L4D2 comes out for the Mac) I've found BlueTooth based wireless mice/keyboards work well for FPS gaming.  But the cheaper RF based devices don't respond quickly enough or tend to drop clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's definitely a mouse that can do this, the [Razer Mamba](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.169418100), looks expensive, but the features include switching between wireless and wired modes, geared specifically towards gaming.